# Postgresql - Group by set of columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by, union

I have a question regarding group by in PostgreSQL.

I am currently looking at the following table:

```
---------------
t1     t2     n
---------------
a      b      1
b      a      2
c      a      4
```

and want to get the following result:

```
---------------
t1     t2     n
---------------
a      b      3
c      a      4
```

In words, I want to group by the set of columns t1 and t2 and sum over the column n within that group. I tried different approaches like the union with t2,t1, however, I am not able to get rid of the "duplicate" entry "b    a    3" in this case.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select least(t1, t2) as t1, greatest(t1, t2) as t2, sum(n)
from the_table
group by least(t1, t2), greatest(t1, t2)
```

This however returns `a,c,4` not `c,a,4` but as you seem to want to treat `a,c` the same as `c,a` this shouldn't make a difference.